# rich:panel set text and X(Close) in header

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying set an text **AND** X (Close) label in header of rich:panel, but I able only one at a time.

Example in:

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/images/figu-Component_Reference-richpopupPanel-Header_and_controls.png

But this example is running with rich:popupPanel, and I need implement in rich:panel component.

I'm tried :

```
<rich:panel>
      <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="Text Header here" />
      </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="controls">
       <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('component')}.hide()return false;">
          <h:outputText value="X" />
       </h:outputLink>
   </f:facet> 
</rich:panel>
```

AND:

```
<rich:panel>
   <f:facet name="header">
           <h:outputText value="Text Header here" />
   </f:facet>
       <f:facet name="controls">
           <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('component')}.hide(); return false;">
               X
           </h:outputLink>
       </f:facet>
</rich:panel>
```

And others, but all not worked

Thanks.

Comment: this is not `rich:panel` but [`rich:popupPanel`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky)

Comment: Yep, but I need implement this features in rich:panel

Comment: Well, let me tell you that `rich:panel` has no `f:facet name="controls"`. What you could do is to put the **X** in the header and send it to the left

Comment: OK, but how I handle event click when user click exactly in "X" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to simulate the same behavior by doing something like

```html
<h:form id="frmTest">
    <rich:panel id="panelTest" style="width: 200px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Text Header here" />
            <div style="position: relative; float: right;">
                <a4j:commandLink
                    onclick="document.getElementById('frmTest:panelTest').style.display='none'; return false;">
                    <h:outputText value="X" />
                </a4j:commandLink>
            </div>
        </f:facet> 
        <p>
            Some text here!
        </p>
    </rich:panel>
    <br />
    <a4j:commandLink onclick="document.getElementById('frmTest:panelTest').style.display='block'; return false;">
        <h:outputText value="Show panel" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```